# Do two identical primitive Dirichlet characters have the same modulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory, characters

If $\chi_1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ q_1),\chi_2\ (\mathrm{mod}\ q_2)$ are primitive Dirichlet characters with $\chi_1(n)=\chi_2(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, can we deduce, that $q_1=q_2$? So far I just got that $(q_1,q_2)>1$: Assume $\mathrm{gcd}(q_1,q_2)=1$ with $q_1,q_2\neq1$. Thus $1=q_1x+q_2y$ for some integers $x,y$. Therefore
\begin{equation}
1=\left|\chi_1(-1)\right|=\left|\chi_1(-1+q_1x)\right|=\left|\chi_2(-q_2y)\right|=0,
\end{equation}
a contradiction.

Comment: Notice that there's nothing to rule out the case $q_1=q_2=1$. So any proof that starts with the assumption $\gcd(q_1,q_2)=1$ can't correctly lead to a contradiction. (Here, if $q_2=1$ then your last equality isn't correct.)

Comment: Your are right, I was too lazy as $q_1=q_2=1$ is the trivial case. But I changed it, and also another mistake in my argumentation: As far as I can see I need more than just $(q_1,q_2)>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\chi_1=\chi_2$ is periodic with period $q_1$ and also periodic with period $q_2$, it is periodic with period $g=\gcd(q_1,q_2)$. Then it must in fact be a Dirichlet character (mod $g$). (A little checking here is required to show that the zero values are all correct.) The primitivity of $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ then implies that $q_1=g=q_2$.